# Fiware Cepheus Configuration file issue

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

Is There is away make Fiware-cepheus Take more than one Configuration file as i wan't  to  sent  Different Data type   and  i  want  to process it  in real  time  but can't  install  different  Cepheus Vm to each Data federation Is there is a way to  make Cepheus take different Configuration Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiware-Cepheus supports an (undocumented...) multi-tenant mode where multiple configurations can live together on the same instance (sharing available memory/CPU resources).

You can enable the `multi-tenant` profile from `app.properties`:

```
 spring.profiles.active=multi-tenant
```

or at boot time with the `--spring.profiles.active=multi-tenant` command line argument.

Then for each request, you can add two HTTP headers `Fiware-Service` (default value: `default`) and `Fiware-ServicePath` (default value: `/`).

`Fiware-Service` header can only contain `[A-Za-z0-9_]` characters, `Fiware-ServicePath` header must start with a `/`.

Each tenant needs its own configuration setup (using the same headers) before it can start processing data.

For more information, please read [related code](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/tree/master/cepheus-cep/src/main/java/com/orange/cepheus/cep/tenant).

Comment: thank you for your answer i know this along time but i enable the multi-tenant profile from app.properties  but  still get  service null service path null

Comment: @Marc we already enable  to  make Cepheus take many Configuration files but we have  problem  with connection between Cepheus Broker and  cep  here more detail [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012933/error-cepheus-broker-not-forwards-updates-to-cepheus-cep]